# empty files with the names of repositories on harddrive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1

Recently I found on my hard drive (Seagate Ironwolf 8TB) the files (in one folder) that look strange

[image]

They appeared to be created recently and they are partially reflect the already existing folders in the same catalog (some other empty files has only one word out of two and so on)

[image]

In addition some games were deleted for some reason (and I didn't to it)

[image]

Their catalogs contain such folders (some for example only `_CommonRedist`).
What might be a problem?

Comment: They seemed to be files linked to command prompt commands. I believe those files should be hidden

Comment: @RACING121 possibly, but I have no idea why and how the appeared there